# Multiple Arguments as one Argument in php

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I'm writing a function that takes three arguments, the first two arguments are strings but I want the third argument to comprise of multiple arguments.
Below is the block of code

```
function myFetch($query, $datatype, $variables){
        include("models.php");
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param($datatype, $variables);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        return $result->fetch_assoc();

        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
}
```

From the above code, I'd like the third argument `$variable` to contain other arguments, example `$variable = $one, $two, $three, $four` of which these arguments have their own data to be passed to the `bind_param` function.

Example of the `$query`, `$datatype` and `$variables`:
`$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ? and visible = ?";`
`$datatype = "ii";`
`$id = 1,$visible = 1;`
`$variables = $id, $visible;`

Comment: Do you want `$variables` to be an *array*?

Comment: if it works in the `bind_param` why not?

Comment: please post an example of $query, $datatype and $variables.

Comment: I've update the question, examples are below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution would be like this:

- Create an empty `$param` array and loop through your argument variable array `$variables` using a `for` loop.
- In each iteration of the loop, push the elements to `$variables` array as a reference.
- Use `array_unshift()` function to push `$datatype` to the beginning of `$variables` array.
- Finally, use `call_user_func_array()` function to bind each of the parameters.

So your `myFetch()` function should be like this:

```
function myFetch($query, $datatype, $variables){
    include("models.php");
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $param = array();
    $count = count($variables);
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i){
        $param[] = &$variables[$i];
    }
    array_unshift($param, $datatype);
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $param);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();

    return $result;
}
```

Subsequently, you can call this function like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ? and visible = ?";
$datatype = "ii";
$variables = array(1, 1);

$result = myFetch($query, $datatype, $variables);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    // display $row details
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do everything you want in your function:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ? and visible = ?";
$variables = array($id, $visible);
function myFetch($query, $variables){
        include("models.php");
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute($variables);
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Just some thoughts:

- Could you use include_once outside your function instead of include?
- When you return a value before you close your connection, it will never get closed

Comment: the function is in a class, the include has to be inside the function

Answer (score 1):

Use [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to call `mysqli::bind_param()`, Example:

```
<?php
$resource = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ? and visible = ?");
$reflectionArray = array(1,"yes");
$reflection = new ReflectionClass('mysqli_stmt');
$method = $reflection->getMethod("bind_param");
$method->invokeArgs($resource, $reflectionArray);
$resource->execute(); 
?>
```

Your function:

```
function myFetch($query, $datatype, $variablesArray){
    include("models.php");
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

    $reflection = new ReflectionClass('mysqli_stmt');
    $method = $reflection->getMethod("bind_param");
    $method->invokeArgs($stmt, $variablesArray);
    $resource->execute(); 

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();

    return $result->fetch_assoc();
}
```

Comment: can you write an example of passing arguments in the above modified function?